# return inside a try/catch vs return in a .catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Why is the behavior of `return` different inside the `catch` of `try/catch` vs inside `.catch` ?

```js
function promise(call, params) {
  return new Promise((keep, brk) => {
    brk(2)
    keep(1)
  })
}

async function a() {
  try {
   var r = await promise()
  } catch (e) {
    return console.error('a catch e', e)
  } 
  console.log('a after catch')
  return r
}

async function b() {
  let r = await promise().catch(e => {
    return console.error('b catch e', e)
  })
  console.log('b after catch')
  return r
}

a().then(v => console.log('a', v))
b().then(v => console.log('b', v))
```

returns

```sh
a catch e 2
b catch e 2
a undefined
b after catch
b undefined
```

Comment: Because a `return` keyword causes a return from the enclosing function. Which is the anonymous `catch` callback, not `b`.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that, as pointed out by @Berji's comment, your catch's return statement does not have the same enclosing parent function in `a` and `b`.

- In `a`, it is enclosed directly inside the function `a`
- In `b`, it is enclosed inside an anonymous function that is itself enclosed inside the function `b`.

This means that in the latter case, **it is the anonymous function inside `b` that is returning**, not `b` itself.

This explains why in your output, `b after catch` is being printed but not `a after catch`: `a` is returning before the console log gets called.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. seems odd that the two catches dont behave the same: i dont have the ability to upvote or close this issue, but thanks